# Embedding SVG image into a webpage: different behaviour in FF

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I've just been trying to embed a simple animated SVG image into a HTML web-page with mixed success. After exploring the web a bit, I've found a number of ways to do it and included some in the following example: http://www.theinsanewonderland.com/loli/mekakucityactors/index_test.html

But on my *Firefox* (v.31, 64bit, Ubuntu) the behavior is quite inconsistent:

- `<object>`: Behavior as expected, i.e. background image is shown and animation works as expected (+/- 30s for the hands to go once around).
- `<img>`: Background image is not loaded; animation freezes after roughly 20° and then resets a few seconds later (but before the whole 30s of the circumnavigation have passed).
- `<div>` with `background`: same as `<img>`
- `<iframe>`: same as `<object>`

Does someone have any experience with this and can explain the differences? And do you observe the same effects with other browsers?

PS:
Just tried *Chromium*, where everything works fine and consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used as an image i.e. a CSS background or via an `<img>` tag an SVG file must be complete in a single file. You need to embed the jpeg background image file as a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) within the SVG file itself.

The animation problem is an example of [bug 1067375](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1067375) which I fixed a while ago. The fix will appear in Firefox 35 which will be released on 12th of January. You can download an [early beta release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/) of that now if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but is this the same effect? My moving object is not covered by any transparent shape, rather its the top-level element. And the missing background is neither explained by it (note that the page's background colors is correctly visible through the object i.e. its not an issue of transparency).

Comment: Curious: While https://bug1067375.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8489377 does not appear animated, the hands magically change positions after a switching away from and back to the tab :)

Comment: Switching tabs forces a repaint. The animation occurs, it just doesn't repaint.

Comment: With version 35, including latest update from the beta-channel, the animtation works just fine, thanks for the bug-fix! Sadly, the background is still not showing up.

Comment: Interesting... any idea why only data URIs work? The resulting SVG files can't really be called pretty...

Comment: Because external files would be a privacy hole: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628747#c0